# Node update not working, format is wrong while send to api

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I try to update my data from Angular to Node.js

component.ts

```
updatefunction(id,data){
    console.log("component",data);
    //component {role: "User", _id: "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd", name: "Test", email: "test123@gmail.com", //username: "Test"}
    this.uAdminService
      .updateUser(id,data).subscribe(
        result => {
          //console.log(result.json());
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.json());
        }
      );

  }
```

in myservice.ts

```
updatefunction(id, data){
      console.log("service", data);
       //service {role: "User", _id: "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd", name: "Test", email: "test123@gmail.com", //username: "Test"}
       let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': this.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.put(this.url+id, data, options);
}
```

my nodejs controller

```
router.put('/:id', VerifyToken, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    //{'{\n "role": "User", \n "_id": "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd" \n}'}
        User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true}).select("-password")
        .then(users => {
            res.send(users);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Report."
            });
        });


});
```

my req.body console like this **{'{\n "role": "User", \n "_id": "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd" \n}'} but i pass from angularjs in this format {role: "User", _id: "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd", name: "Test", email: "test123@gmail.com", //username: "Test"}**

I don't know why it's converting so that it's not update to db

if i console from api it will like this  **{ name: "Test",email: "test123@gmail.com"}**

Answer (score 0):

Update `myservice.ts` like below:

```js
updatefunction(id, data){
      console.log("service", data);
       //service {role: "User", _id: "5c2dc052d6bfba36b41b34dd", name: "Test", email: "test123@gmail.com", //username: "Test"}
       let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': this.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       return this.http.put(this.url+id, data, options);
}
```

Changed the `Content-Type` to `application/json` as you are sending a `json` formatted data and not `form` data.

Comment: I tried already if i use application/json. req.body return empty

Comment: Are you using the `body-parser` middleware and parsing for json data?

Comment: I use this app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: if i print res.send(users); after update it will show previous recode only not a new one

Comment: also add `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: is the endpoint been activated by the request because it all seems fine to me.